# Replacing last four digits in a set of numbers that are separated by dashes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, replace, substitution

I have a bunch of numbers similar to SSNs in format, and would like to change the final number set to the same.  So if the number structure is like this "123-45-6700", I want to have a formula to change the final number ONLY.  So the "123-45" portion can be whatever, but I want to be able to change all of the 6789, 6790, 6745, to 6700.  Does this make sense?  I've been doing replacements, but it's tedious.  Thank you!

Mostly find and replace, or manually.

Comment: Try: `=TEXTBEFORE(A1:A100,"-",2)&"-6700"`

Comment: But if it starts 68xx or 69xx should they be changed?

Answer (score 1):

Just like I have posted in comments above using <kbd>TEXTBEFORE()</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(G3#,"-",2)&"-6700"
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=REPLACE(G3#,8,4,6700)
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=LEFT(G3#,7)&"-6700"
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>G3</kbd>

```
=SUBSTITUTE(G3#,RIGHT(G3#,4),6700)
```

---

Please change `G3#` to your original range as per your suit. In example I have used this to generate some random series.

```
 =RANDARRAY(10,,100,200,1)&"-"&
  RANDARRAY(10,,10,50,1)&"-"&
  RANDARRAY(10,,6700,7000,1)
```

---

As in comments below **[Solar Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961700/solar-mike)** Sir, pointed out that if it categorically needs to be replaced those which starts with `67` then you could try the following :

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>H3</kbd>

```
=CHOOSE(N(--LEFT(RIGHT(G3#,4),2)=67)+1,G3#,LEFT(G3#,7)&6700)
```

---

Comment: Should that also change the 68xx and 69xx as well?

Comment: No sir, in example I have generated some series using `RANDARRAY()` so its showing. But  OP said in subject line _Replacing last four digits in a set of numbers that are separated by dashes_ so assumed they might be having only those

Comment: But OP actually said "but I want to be able to change all of the 6789, 6790, 6745, to 6700" so what you do does not seem to be correct as you change 68xx to 67xx etc

Comment: You are correct Sir, let OP respond. Otherwise we will not know

Comment: @SolarMike Sir, thank you for correcting me, I have made some changes! Thanks again Sir!

Answer (score 1):

`=TEXTBEFORE(A1,"-",-1)&"-"&FLOOR(TEXTAFTER(A1,"-",-1),100)`

Will convert the last for digits to the closest multiple of 100 smaller or equal to given number.

Or `=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,2,"00")`